# Setup VAT for administrator only in magento 1.5.x

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

We have setup a magento store. We are not charging any Tax/VAT to our customer. But in some countries we have to pay Tax/VAT which should be calculated for the administrator reports only. So we know how much we have to pay as Tax/VAT for the order. We can set all the product as non taxable but that rule will also apply to the administrator reports which we do not want. So for example if actual price is 60 for a product we will only charge 60 to the customer and pay Tax/VAT from ourself in the countries we have to pay Tax/VAT?

Can anybody let me know if its possible and if yes, how?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After hours of struggling I edited the following to make this happen

app\code\core\Mage\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax.php and commented the

/* $this->_addAmount($totalTax);
            $this->_addBaseAmount($baseTotalTax);
            $this->_saveAppliedTaxes($address, $data['applied_rates'], $totalTax, $baseTotalTax, $rate);*/

This is around at line 570.